# What is a pyarrow table? Will it be a replacement for pandas dataframes?

Tags: pandas, pyarrow

I have tried reading the docs, but I am still confused. Are pyarrow tables able to do groupbys and all the wonderful pandas functionalities ?

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
```

But now for the anticlimax:

```
table["a"]
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-18-fb884245e2de> in <module>()
# ----> 1 table["a"]
# table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Table.__getitem__()
# TypeError: an integer is required
table[0]
# <pyarrow.lib.Column object at 0x111306330>
# chunk 0: <pyarrow.lib.Int64Array object at 0x11728d1d8>
# [
# 1,
# 2,
# 3
# ]

c = table[0]
c[c>2]
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-16-cc54312229de> in <module>()
# ----> 1 c[c>2]
# 
# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'pyarrow.lib.Column' and 'int'
```

Is pyarrow a library more meant for pandas internals ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, pyarrow is a library for building data frame internals (and other data processing applications). It is not an end user library like pandas. If you wish to discuss further, please write on the Apache Arrow mailing list.